# HTML5 Canvas, Text and JavaScript

Tags: html, canvas

I have a script that writes text on a canvas. It works fine.  The problem is if I make an Ajax call to first get the string and then secondly write the string to the canvas, JavaScript seems to ignore the order that I want things done and write the string before the Ajax call; the result is the script prints to the canvas 'undefined'.

psuedocode:

```
//var str = ~some_ajax_call...  <---If I use this, the output is undefined.
var str = "hello world";

context.fillStyle    = '#00f';
context.font         = 'italic 30px sans-serif';
context.textBaseline = 'top';
context.fillText  (str, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is `assync`, so your code below the ajax call runs before the response from the server. You need to run your code only when the HTTP Response is received.

With jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "sample.php",
  success: function(d) {
    context.fillStyle    = '#00f';
    context.font         = 'italic 30px sans-serif';
    context.textBaseline = 'top';
    context.fillText  (d, 0, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As ajax calls are asynchronous, you'll have to put your printing logic in the `success` callback of the ajax op.

For example:

```
var str = "hello world";

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    success: function(data){
        var context = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle    = '#00f';
        context.font         = 'italic 30px sans-serif';
        context.textBaseline = 'top';
        context.fillText  (str, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhENZ/